# Cannot install anything Properly & Vlc Crashing if I run any kind of video file

Tags: video, vlc, crash

I have been using VLC for a long time but nowadays it just crashes / cancels itself with no error showing) when I run any sort of VIDEO files,

So I tried to install it again but anything I install it gives the error shown in the screen shot.

Any Suggestions on what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get -f install`.
If it doesn't work, then try configuring the libraries as mentioned in screenshot.